# Postgresql equivalent of read write application user

Tags: postgresql

I have limited PostgreSQL knowledge and would like to update my application json config so that it uses a standard read and write access level user rather than the sys admin level one I'm currently using to connect to the database.

I am familiar with SQL Server and this is super simple to do however I don't have much in the way of PostgreSQL database admin type skills.

Do I create a user for this or a role, or both? I have seen examples of roles being used but I don't know if this is best. Also, would I need to mention the database schema?

Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this in a SQL script. In terms of what I have found code-wise, an example from the official docs is:

```
CREATE ROLE name [ [ WITH ] option [ ... ] ]
```

Can somebody please advise?

Comment: In postgres, a "user" is just a role that can login. Otherwise it's all roles, couldn't be any simpler :-) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html

Answer (score 1):

You never, ever use a superuser for your application.

Just make sure that your application user has been `GRANT`ed all required privileges on the tables, sequences etc.

One easy way to do that is to make the application user the owner of these objects, that is, the application user is used to create all tables etc.